# How do I support a Many-Many Join Table in Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I have a Many-Many join in the dataset I want to store on a mobile device.

Since AzureMobile Apps seems to synchronize all data in a given table I think I need to synchronize 3 separate tables.

Furthermore, I'm not sure how to expose my data context

Any direction is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Apps doesn't handle relationships at all by itself, so you'll have to manage the foreign keys yourself. It's worthwhile reading Adrian Hall's blog post about [relationships in Mobile Apps](https://adrianhall.gitlab.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/) for general pointers.

So yes, for a many-many relationship you will want to expose the three tables, e.g. Book, Author and the join table BookAuthor, which would have bookId and authorId columns. Configure your app and Mobile App service to sync all three tables.